# Angular upload simple file

Tags: angular, file-upload

Hello all i was triying to make just the example from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-uploader  , but for some reason it is working but when it click on upload File it says
Upload Failed !

im just following the example 1st one here is the code
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-uploader

### (1st time posting in here so if i make any blunders please forgive me....)

`uploadAPI:  { url:"https://example-file-upload-api", method:"POST", headers: {`

The problem its here since in this Example hes using a public Api , im kinda new but  i wanted to create one so it can be use on the same computer .  can anyone help me ?

Comment: take a look at this code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload it really simple and dont need to install any extra packages

Comment: Can you post how you are implementing it? 
What's the error you might be are receiving?

Comment: uploadAPI:  {
      url:"https://example-file-upload-api",
      method:"POST",
      headers: {

The problem its here since in this Example hes using a public Api , im kinda new but  i wanted to create one so it can be use on the same computer .  can anyone help me ?